# Place a figure at the top of the next page

Tags: floats, positioning

I wanted to place a figure at the top of the next page.

```
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
\begin{figure}[htbf]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/studyArea.jpg}
        \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
    \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment (a) the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system (b) the distribution of the nodes in the study site \citep{r33}}
    \label{fig:study area}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
\blindtext
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear. Do you want to *place* the figure at the top of the next page?

Comment: use only `[t]` if it should be on the next page. I suppose that you do not need `\FloatBarrier`. And by the way: there is no option `f`for the placement of a float,

Comment: @egreg, YEs, exactly.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to be absolutely sure that the figure will be placed at the top of the *next* page (as opposed to, possibly, the top of the page where the `\begin{figure}` directive is detected), you should use the `afterpage` package and its `\afterpage` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,natbib,lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\afterpage{%
  \begin{figure}[t!] % use "t!" to force the float to start the float at top of page
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/studyArea.jpg}
        \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
    \caption{The Grand St.~Bernard wireless sensor network deployment 
      (a) the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system 
      (b) the distribution of the nodes in the study site \citep{r33}}
    \label{fig:studyarea} % better not to have a space in the "label"
  \end{figure}
} % end of "afterpage" group
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

Addendum: Assuming that the line you wish to draw between the graph and caption should span the entire width of the text block, I would recommend using the command `\rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}` instead of `\rule{35em}{0.3pt}`.

Comment: It appears at top of the page but it appears before the placed site.

Comment: @aliamidi - Does the `\afterpage` instruction maybe occur at the very top of the page? If so, maybe insert a `\null` instruction right before `\afterpage` in order to force the float to the next page. (Note also that I've edited the MWE in the meantime to replace the `\blindtext` directives with `\lipsum` directives.)

Comment: it cannot address the problem again.

Comment: @aliamidi - I'm not sure I know how to interpret your comment. Are you unable to repeat the problem you're describing -- in which case my proposed solution works for you? Please advise.

Comment: Your code send the figure to the top of the page but it occurs before the cited palce.

Comment: @aliamidi - Evidently my adaptation of your code snippets doesn't fully capture the problem you're facing. Please consider editing your original question to create a full MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problem you're encountering -- even *after* encasing the `figure` float in an `\afterpage{}` directive. Thanks.

Comment: Can we apply this solution for `figure*`?

Comment: @alper -- Not sure I understand what you're asking. In all document classes I'm familiar with, `figure*` environments are *always* placed at the top of a page. No need for the `\afterpage` device proposed in this answer, for sure.