# Dealing with columns while placing a figure at the top of next page

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I am using `ACM template` and having problem while placing the figure at the top of next page.
I read threads here, but still instead of placing the figure at the top of whole page it only places it at the top of next column.

> I am using following commands:
>   [Place a figure at the top of the next page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85853/place-a-figure-at-the-top-of-the-next-page)

I want it to be like this:
[image]

---

But it happens to be like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}`.

Comment: Thanks, it did a trick. Why I can't vote up your comment -_-?

Comment: Don't worry about comment upvote, most important is having solved the problem :) I think a similar problem has already been solved in other questions: when I find the most similar question, I would propose to close this as duplicate of the other. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes sure, sorry for being redundant.